# Having trouble connecting Appium Pytest with LambdaTest, specifcally with capabilities

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, appium

I'm trying to connect a simple test case I developed in PyCharm using Appium and Pytest to LambdaTest for future automation. I run the test locally and it works, but when I try to run it on Lambda I get the following error:

> AssertionError: Driver capabilities must be defined

I'll share some of my code, first is the class where I set the capabilities:

```
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

class Driver:

def getDriverMethod(self):
    capabilities = {
        "platformName": "android",
        "deviceName": "Galaxy S22 5G",
        "platformVersion": "13",
        "visual": True,
        "network": True,
        "build": "LoginAlpha",
        "name": "Login Test",
        "project": "Asd",
        "deviceOrientation": "portrait",
        "isRealMobile": True,
        "app": "lt://APP10160281841703283833230614"
    }

    options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities)

    url = "https://(myuser):(myaccesskey)@mobile-hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub"
    driver = webdriver.Remote(url, options=options)
    return driver`
```

I followed LambdaTest-specific capabilities in a specific generator they have and tried changing various details and settings instead of capabilities ("android" to "Android") but nothing worked.

I share the basic part of my test code even though it's not everything:

```
import pytest
import unittest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("beforeClass", "beforeMethod")
class LoginPositiveTest(unittest.TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def classObjects(self):
    self.bp = BasePage(self.driver)

def test_positiveLogin(self):
    self.bp.clickElement(*IntroL.skip_the_tour)
    self.bp.clickElement(*HomepageL.geo_while_using_app)
    self.bp.clickElement(*HomepageL.my_lotto)`
```

Finally, I set the `beforeClass` function to set up the driver:

```
import pytest
import time
from AppiumFramework.base.DriverClass import Driver

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def beforeClass(request):
    driver1 = Driver()
    driver = driver1.getDriverMethod()
    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
    driver.quit()`
```

Please, I can't find anything that helps

I tried various minor fixes like changing variable names and adding other capabilities like "app", "appPackage", "appActivity", etc.

I also printed capabilities to see if they were okay.